# If $f$ has a local extremum at $\vec a$, if $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$, then show that $\vec\nabla f(\vec a)=\vec 0.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:D\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\vec a$  be some interior point of $D$. If $f$ has a local extremum at $\vec a$, and if $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$, then show that $\vec\nabla f(\vec a)=\vec 0.$

Attempt: Let $f=f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$. Let $\vec a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)$ be a local extremum of $f$. We have to show that $f_{x_i}(\vec a)=0$ for $i=1,2,3,\cdots , x_n$. How to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is more than one way to do this. But, assuming we know how extremals behave for real-valued functions $F\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, one may proceed as follows. Consider your point $\overrightarrow{a}$ where the minumun sits. Then in any direction $\overrightarrow{h}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we move, we will see that the function
$$F(s):=f(\overrightarrow{a}+s\overrightarrow{h})$$ has a local minimum at $s=0$. If you apply the chain rule you will find that, for every $\overrightarrow{h}$ we have $(\nabla f)(\overrightarrow{a})\cdot \overrightarrow{h}=0$, and therefore $(\nabla f)(\overrightarrow{a})=0$. For local maxima, the reasoning is the same.